# How to remove: footer's bottom-margin and fancyhdr's auto-displayed line?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, boxes

I use a header (blue rule and image) and a footer (blue rule).

**I have 2 issues that I'm trying to solve:**

**1.** I want my footer rule to touch the very bottom of the page (there is some bottom-margin of sorts currently). How can I achieve that? (see image below)

[image]

**2.** I don't know how to remove that random black line appearing on the header. It seems to appear when I include "\pagestyle{fancy}" or "\thispagestyle{fancy}" - but without them, my header won't show at all. Any ideas on how to remove that black line? And why does it appear in the first place? (see image below)

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[9pt, legalpaper]{article}

\usepackage[legalpaper,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{highlight_colour}{HTML}{067dac}    % bright blue
% ==============================================
% HEADER AND FOOTER (.sty file)
% ==============================================
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % uses a stylised header and footer
\usepackage{graphicx} % to manage images

\pagestyle{fancy} % to display it on pages
\thispagestyle{fancy} % to display it on the first page too
\fancyhf{} % remove everything
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\chead{
    \makebox[\linewidth]{\color{highlight_colour}\rule{\paperwidth}{3pt}}
    \makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics{header_design02.PNG}}
}
\cfoot{
    \makebox[\linewidth]{\color{highlight_colour}\rule{\paperwidth}{3pt}}
}

% ==============================================
% BODY OF THE DOCUMENT (.tex file)
% ==============================================
\begin{document}
    {\large Title}

    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Img file:
[image]

Comment: This code is not compilable: highlight_colour is not defined, the '(x)color` package is not loaded, and most importantly, we don't even know the dimensions of the image in the header.

Comment: You can replace the 'highlight_colour' with any other pre-existing color name e.g. 'red' - that does not affect the issues I'm having in any way. But here's how i defined it \definecolor{highlight_colour}{HTML}{067dac}. I haven't set in Latex the dimensions of the image - i just called the image file as is.

Comment: Yes, but we don't have this image, so my answer uses the `[demo]` option for `\includegraphics`. Always post compilable codes so we can test instantly and see what happens.

Comment: Well noted, thank you. I've edited my post to include the img file and custom blue color code. Your answer below has worked, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Note, that using `eso-pic`, it will simpler to add the page number, to, say, the footer.

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know. Sorry, can't upvote your answer due to my low reputation score

Comment: It's quite unimportant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is removed by setting `\headrulewidth` to 0pt. As to the rules at the top and bottom of the paper sheet, it is simpler to do that with `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass[9pt, legalpaper]{article}

\usepackage[legalpaper,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{highlight_colour}{SteelBlue}
% ==============================================
% HEADER AND FOOTER (.sty file)
% ==============================================
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % uses a stylised header and footer
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % to manage images

\pagestyle{fancy} % to display it on pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\thispagestyle{fancy} % to display it on the first page too
\fancyhf{} % remove everything
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\chead{\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics{header_design02.PNG}}
}
\cfoot{}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageLowerLeft{{\color{highlight_colour}\rule{\paperwidth}{3pt}}}\AtPageUpperLeft{{\color{highlight_colour}\rule[-3pt]{\paperwidth}{3pt}}}}
% ==============================================
% BODY OF THE DOCUMENT (.tex file)
% ==============================================
\begin{document}
    {\large Title}

    \lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]